# How to show only those records which are active

Tags: php, laravel

I have two fields deposit and monthly and i want to show only those values of deposit which are active in monthly fields.

Here i have share screen shot with you[image: here you can see i want to show only those values of deposit which are active in monthly but its show all the fields of deposit]

My Code:
This code is for deposit

```
                <td>
                                                @if($season->deposit==0)
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deposit[]" value="{{@$propertyd->pivot->deposit}}">
                                                    </div>
                                                @else
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="deposit[]">
                                                @endif
                                            </td>
```

and this for monthly

```
<td>
                                            @if($season->allow_monthly_rates==1)
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="monthly_rate[]" value="{{@$propertyd->pivot->monthly_rate}}">
                                                </div>
                                            @else
                                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="monthly_rate[]">
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
```

if i changed deposit==1 nothing is changing.
Here your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: As i understand from your question you want to hide the deposit field if  the monthly one is hidden right?

Comment: yeah exactly i want to do that

Comment: How i can do that any suggestion?

Comment: I wrote an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the condition of deposit field to be like the following

```
@if($season->allow_monthly_rates==1 && $season->deposit==0)
```